# Ordenar una array de objetos por un atributo

Tags: javascript, poo, ordenamiento

La cuestión es que tengo este *Array* de objetos.

> ```
> (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> 0: {id: 143, nombre: "1"}
> 1: {id: 208, nombre: "10"}
> 2: {id: 209, nombre: "Madrid"}
> 3: {id: 144, nombre: "Lugo"}
> 4: {id: 145, nombre: "3"}
> 5: {id: 152, nombre: "4"}
> ```

Necesito ordenar por el atributo, nombre que puede ser letras o números.

Intente seguir ejemplos como:

```javascript
users.sort(function (a, b){
    return ( b.nombre.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.nombre.toLowerCase()))
});
```

Pero no lo hace correctamente, el resultado debe de ser el siguiente:

> ```
>   (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>     0: {id: 143, nombre: "1"}
>     1: {id: 208, nombre: "3"} 
>     2: {id: 209, nombre: "4"} 
>     3: {id: 144, nombre: "10"} 
>     4: {id: 145, nombre: "Lugo"} 
>     5: {id: 152, nombre: "Madrid"}
> ```

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: En un sitio pone `name`, en el otro `nombre`. ¿Puede ser ese el motivo? Si no es ese, explica un poco qué quiere decir ese "no lo hace correctamente"

Comment: no , lo de abajo es para ordenar alfabéticamente y necesito que ordene tanto los números como las letras. Es decir el resultado debe ser primero los números ordenados y luego las ciudades ordenas alfabéticamente.

Comment: Alfabétiamente "10" está antes que "2", del mismo modo que "ba" está delante de "c", ¿Ese es tu problema?

Comment: Puedes intentar usar 2 arrays, en el primero solo  los números 
se obtiene usando filter y un regex. El segundo array es de ciudades. Luego ordenas de manera separada los números y las ciudades con sort y finalmente unes los arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar el método sort() junto a localeCompare() como lo estabas realizando pero debes indicar que también puedes comparar números. Eso lo logras mediante el uso de un objeto de opciones que te proporciona el método y también debes establecer la configuración regional, debido a que los resultados proporcionados por localeCompare() varían de un idioma a otro.

```
users.sort(function (a, b){
    return a.nombre.localeCompare(b.nombre, 'en', { numeric: true })
});
```

Comment: Gracias a todos , las dos respuestas me valieron.

Answer (score 1):

**¿Qué tal?**

Propongo la siguiente solución, apoyándome en los comentarios valiosos a su pregunta y como sugiere @davidbug podría lograrse de la siguiente manera haciendo uso de:

`flatMap`: Devuelve una versión aplanada del arreglo.

`match con regex:` Obtiene las ocurrencias de una expresión regular.

`sort`: Devuelve un arreglo ordenado.

`filter`: Crea un nuevo arreglo con todos los elementos que cumplan una condición.

`spreat:` Permite a un elemento iterable ser expandido (concatenación para esta solución).

```
const data = [
      {id: 143, nombre: "1"},
      {id: 208, nombre: "10"},
      {id: 209, nombre: "Madrid"},
      {id: 144, nombre: "Lugo"},
      {id: 145, nombre: "3"},
      {id: 152, nombre: "4"}
    ]
```

```
const nums = data.flatMap(curr=> curr.nombre.match(/(\d+)/g))
.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
.filter(num => num)
 
const strings = data.flatMap(curr=> curr.nombre.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
.filter(string => string)
.sort((a,b)=> a.localeCompare(b))
   
console.log([...nums,...strings])
```

**NUMBERS:** flatMap toma los valores con la llave que necesita, en este caso nombre, y devuelve el arreglo aplanado con solo los números(números en una cadena) con la condición aplicada usando `match()`. Luego, filter "elimina" los valores nulos(el texto), y por ultimo se ordena el arreglo usando sort de forma ascendente.

**STRING:** Se aplica el mismo método, con la diferencia que match() devuelve solo alfabeto(letra en una cadena) y sort usa `localCompare()` en caso de tener tildes en su objeto.

Finalmente spreat operator devuelve un nuevo arreglo concatenando NUMS Y STRING

Espero aportar, ¡Saludos!